# How to create custom identifier in program/process for its lifetime?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, process

I am creating a CGI application that launches other processes, they have to be launched through the shell, so I cannot set the UseShellExecute property to false (unfortunately).
I tried to set the applications identifier by defining my custom environment variable in the process

```
        ProcessStartInfo _processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        _processStartInfo.FileName = application;
            _processStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = workingdirectory;
            _processStartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
            _processStartInfo.EnvironmentVariables.Add("GAMERVPS_UID", uid);
        _processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        _processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        Process myProcess = Process.Start(_processStartInfo);
```

But, ofcourse windows does not allow this. Is there any way to provide my custom identifier to the application?

without the commandline, some applications do not work when unknown command line parameters are passed, others misbehave, but some do work when passing custom command line parameters..

Why do I need this?

I need to manage applications without a file for saving PID's or a database, so this would be the best way (IMHO).

I then designed the following code:

```
    public static bool IsProcessRunning(string processname, string uid = "")
    {
        Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName(processname);
        if(uid.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (Process proc in pname)
            {
                if (proc.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables.ContainsKey("GAMERVPS_UID"))
                {
                    if (proc.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables["GAMERVPS_UID"] == uid)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            if (pname.Length == 0)
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }
    }
    public static void KillProcess(string processname, string uid = "")
    {
        Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName(processname);
        if (uid.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (Process proc in pname)
            {
                if (proc.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables.ContainsKey("GAMERVPS_UID"))
                {
                    if (proc.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables["GAMERVPS_UID"] == uid)
                    {
                        proc.Kill();
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (Process proc in pname)
            {
                proc.Kill();
            }
        }
    }
```

But I can't use it.

Are there other methods for unique identifing processes? (ofcourse by providing a custom identifier)

Comment: Note that using shell execute does not guarantee you new process at the end (i.e. documents often would open in existing running application)

Comment: Any suggestions on any other methods of launching and managing processes are also okay